# Can I use my own device as redirect URI with OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm building an application in a device (Point of Sale) and for this I need to use OAuth servers to authenticate a webservice request, the guys on the side of the webservice are now asking me for a redirect URI, I do not have any experience on this so I started googling around 'redirect URI's, so now I wonder, given that this app works on a device (not on cloud), is there a way I can use my own device as the redirect URI and catch the webservice response there (such as the JSON)?

Extra info it might work (or not): In my office we all use DHCP but we have a configurable server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to redirect to your own device if it is running its own web server.

This is because the redirect URI is passed back to the requesting client's browser which performs the redirect as shown in the diagram below from [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/oauth2.0/authorization_code.htm). From there the browser can redirect to a local device's web server using the following approaches:

1. Use `localhost` or the `127.0.0.1` loopback IP for the redirect URI. This will work in the client's browser but not all services may allow registering a redirect URL to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.
2. Use an external host which is mapped to the local system. On a Linux system, this can be configured by placing the hostname the `/etc/hosts` file and pointing it to the local system loopback IP address, e.g. `127.0.0.1`. This can point to a real server on the Internet which is just redirected on the local system so this approach can be used with any service.

An example `/etc/hosts` file can contain a hostname like `example.com` which is then used in the redirect URI.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost example.com
```

Read more about localhost and the loopback IP address on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

[image]

Diagram courtesy of [TutorialsPoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/oauth2.0/authorization_code.htm).